# Difference between using @SuiteClasses anotation and using an Array of classes in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am currently learning JUnit. I came across two ways of passing multiple classes into runClasses method, ie. with @SuitClasses annotation and with an Array of classes.

```java
@RunWith(Suite.class)               
@SuiteClasses({MyClass1.class,MyClass2.class})  
public class MySuiteClass {}

...

Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(MySuiteClass.class);
```

```java
Class<?>[] carr = {MyClass1.class,MyClass2.class};
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(carr);
```

Is there any difference between both methods and when should I be using either of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're equivalent. However, you're probably best off not doing this at all. Most folks use a build tool (mvn or gradle usually) and have that run the tests automatically. That way you don't need to maintain a list of all the test classes you want to run.